# Element does not disappear in android Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have the following element:

[image]

And then I use jquery `fadeOut()`, then `remove()` method to remove the yellow element.

This works perfectly in every browser *except* in **android Chrome**, which looks like the picture above.

The element is supposed to be removed, yet still, it exists on the screen unless I change the phone orientation.

I used chrome inspector, through Remote debugging, to check the element, and indeed the element is removed as revealed in the element panel. I just wonder why the element still shows on the screen.

[image]

The element with class `LMnwtItem` clearly is left with one, with display being none, yet on the screen, still showing the element.

Any help is much appreciated.

btw, sorry for being unable to show the codes.

**ONE MORE INFORMATION WHICH MAY HELP**

The element, however, will disappear after hiding the parent element and then showing the parent element again, but only manually.

Comment: Please could you provide some code that we can try out, preferably something minimal but replicable. Also, you mentioned that you used the Chrome Inspector - did you use Remote Debugging on the mobile device or were you referring to inspecting Chrome Desktop?

Comment: I used Remote Debugging. Sorry that I cannot show the code, but I'm sure somewhere else in my code is having problem. I just wonder if there were similar cases in the past.

Comment: I can't see anything glaringly wrong to me. You could check the Styles panel on the right for`LMnwtItem` and see if the class selector has a `display` property with the `!important` flag, as that would force it to take precedence over inline styling. However, since it doesn't seem to be a problem in other browsers, I'm not sure that would be the case. I can only guess from what I can see unfortunately.